# Масштабирование разметки в Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Как сделать разметку Android приложения так, что бы оно отображалось абсолютно идентично на любых размерах экрана? (аналог `<ViewBox>` или `ScaleTransform` на .NET WPF)

Например, задать размер главного Layout 1920x1080, сделать верстку в этом разрешении, а потом растягивать все это на весь экран.

Если соотношение сторон экрана отличается - заполнять область черным цветом.

Answer (score 1):

возможно вам подойдет [PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите использовать AndroidAPI для создания интерфейса приложения, то, скорее всего, никак. Он сам автоматически настраивает размеры элементов в соответствии с dpi устройства. Можно создать ScrollView с LinearLayout'ом внутри, чтобы были видны все элементы интерфейса на устройстве с маленьким экраном. Чтобы добиться желаемого вами результата, нужно будет изобретать свой велосипед с использованием OpenGL ES.